# Jackson parsing issue with German umlaut (ö)

Tags: utf-8, jackson

My Json payload has German umlaut (ö) and jackson parsing is failing with below exception.how to fix it?

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x6e
at [Source: xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx.core.helpers.HttpServletRequestWrapper$1@3eb7f248; line: 2, column: 29]
```

Payload:

```
{
  "type":1,
  "amount":100,
  "description":"bonificaócin",
  "hold_only":true,
  "ref_data":
    {
      "TPID": 9
    }
 }
```

Comment: That's not actually an umlaut in your text, it's "ó". What's the source of that data? JSON is supposed to always use UTF-8, if it doesn't that's the fault of the producer. If you have control over it, it would be much better to fix the producing side.

Comment: @JoachimSauer JSON can be encoded in UTF-8, 16 and 32 - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-8.1

Comment: Speculation warning! There's a slim chance that your payload is UTF-16 encoded. The `ó` in UTF-16 is `0x00F3`, which would make a UTF-8 decoder think it's expecting three following bytes. A super forgiving decoder might ignore `0x00` bytes, work from the end and give up when `0x6E` doesn't contain a leading 1 bit.

Comment: This is a jersey based rest service. I have no control over the source as multiple clients call it. Is there a configuration or a web filter i can use to sanitize/encode the content?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack: I stand corrected, although I think that if the source JSON was UTF-16 or UTF-32, he'd be getting a different error message (as the parser seems to try to decode with UTF-8, which would result in malformed input for JSON in UTF-16 or UTF-32).

Comment: @Rohan, please provide some source code from the point where you handle the request. Also, can you provide the raw (no copy or paste) JSON message as a download?